# Aligning text along a sector of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

How can I align text along the circumference of a circle like this using TikZ? 
Please ignore the icons. I tried using paths and decorations, but I don't know how to constrain the text to each sector.

This is the code I used to draw the circles and the sectors

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(3cm);
    \foreach \x in {0,45,...,360} {
            % lines from center to point
            \draw[black] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:3cm);
                              }
     \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the code for the circle and sectors without the text? Please add it to the question, so we a) can see how you've set things up and b) don't have to do everything from scratch.

Comment: Sure, @TorbjørnT.

Comment: Search for `text along path` in the PGFmanual or on [this site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btikz-pgf%5D+text+along+path) to get an idea how to approach this.

Comment: Please always post a complete, minimal example. Can you make your code compilable and provide the text you want to use, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metapost would give better results, but if you wish to use TikZ, `decorations.text` offers a variety of options.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (3cm);
  \foreach \i/\j/\k in {0/something/tadpole,45/anything/cauldron,90/another/bread soup,135/whatever/rock candy,180/whenever/lollipop,225/whoever/Bell of Bow,270/why ever/seesaw,315/nothing/roundabout} {
    \draw [black] (0,0) -- (\i:3cm);
    \path [decorate, decoration={text along path, text=\j, text align=center}] (\i:27.5mm) arc (\i:{\i+45}:27.5mm);
    \path [decorate, decoration={text along path, text=\k, text align=center}] (\i:24mm) arc (\i:{\i+45}:24mm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arced text]

## EDIT

To align the text nicely with different directions, it is probably best to use `text effects along path`. This is slower, but it makes it possible to align each character vertically. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    arc text/.style={%
      decorate,
      decoration={%
        text effects along path,
        text={#1},
        text align=center,
        text effects/.cd,
        text along path,
        characters={anchor=mid},
      }
    }
  ]
  \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (3cm);
  \foreach \i/\j/\k [evaluate=\i as \m using {\i < 180 ? \i+45 : \i }, evaluate=\i as \n using { \i < 180 ? \i : \i+45 } ] in {0/something/tadpole,45/anything/cauldron,90/another/bread soup,135/whatever/rock candy,180/whenever/lollipop,225/whoever/Bell of Bow,270/why ever/seesaw,315/nothing/roundabout} {
    \draw [black] (0,0) -- (\i:3cm);
    \path [arc text/.expanded=\j] (\m:27.5mm) arc (\m:\n:27.5mm);
    \path [arc text/.expanded={\k}] (\m:24mm) arc (\m:\n:24mm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: opposite directions]

Comment: Love the text you've used. How can I change the way the text faces? i.e. Text turned inwards so that the upper quadrants are easier to read?

Comment: You'd need to reverse the path of the arc by saying e.g. `({\i+45}:\i:27.5mm)`. So you probably want to split the `\foreach` into two else you'd need to test the value of `\i` within the loop. The text is just run along the path in the direction of that path, whatever the path happens to be.

Comment: @lexxie Please see edit.