# Write Text Along Sectors Paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations

I Have an organogram in which I have divided each department as a sector of a circle (written in red-coloured text) and the division(s) of each department is/are written within the same sector of a circle (with black-coloured text).

**What I Have**

1. The texts are lined straight in each sector (which is what I do not want).
2. I am good with the text alignment the following are my code and [image: output]:

   \documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
   \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
   \usepackage{newtxtext}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, fadings}
   \tikzfading[name=fade out,
   inner color=transparent!0,
   outer color=transparent!5]

   \tikzset{
   figNode/.style={
   path picture={
   \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {#1};}}
   }
   \usepackage[OT2, OT1]{fontenc}
   \begin{document}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\Nsector{15}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\Asector{360/\Nsector}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\Aorig{30}

   ```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
        arc text/.style={%
            decorate,
            decoration={%
                text effects along path,
                text={#1},
                text align=center,
                text effects/.cd,
                text along path,
                characters={anchor=mid},
            }
        }
        ]


        \foreach[count=\xi] \dpt/\c/\uI in {%
            Human Resurce Mgt/Cyan!70!ForestGreen!40!/App Pro \& Disc\\Training \& Welfare,
            Gen. Service/Cyan!70!Magenta!40!/Gen. Service\\ Maintainance,
            Finance/Cyan!70!ForestGreen!40!/Exp\\ Budget\\ Revenue\\ Financial \& Fiscal Reporting,
            Legal Services \& Board Affair/Cyan!40!YellowOrange!70!/Legal Services\\Board Affairs,
            Comm \& Public Relation/Magenta!70!ForestGreen!40!/Communication\\ Public Affairs,
            Information Communication Tech/Cyan!70!ForestGreen!40!/Sys Prog \& Magtm\\Data Processing \& Analysis\\ Hardware \& Networking,
            Feild Services \& and Method./Cyan!40!ForestGreen!70!/Feild Services\\Methodology,
            National Acc Energy  \& Environment/Cyan!70!ForestGreen!40!/National Account\\ Energy \& Environment,
            Corperate Planning \& Statistical Coordination/Cyan!70!/Corperate Planning \\ Statistical Coordination,
            Agric \& Biz Enter/Cyan!30!/Agric Statistics\\Biz Enterprice,
            Trade \& Prices/Cyan!130!/Trade\\Prices,
            Gender \& Social Stat/ForestGreen!30!/Gender \& Social Inclusion\\Social Stat,
            Intl Statistical Devpt/Cyan!70!YellowOrange!30!/Donor Coordination\\Intl Action Plan,
            Demo \& HH Stat/Cyan!30!YellowOrange!70!/Demographics\\Household,
            Procurement/Cyan!30!ForestGreen!30!YellowOrange!30!/Procurement Plans\\Tender Advertisement
        }
        {\draw[draw=white, fill = \c,thin] (\Aorig-\xi*\Asector:3cm)-- (\Aorig-\xi*\Asector:10cm) arc (\Aorig-\xi*\Asector:\Aorig-\xi*\Asector-\Asector:10) -- (\Aorig-\xi*\Asector-\Asector:3cm) arc (\Aorig-\xi*\Asector-\Asector:\Aorig-\xi*\Asector:3);
            \draw[decoration={text along path,
                text={|\bfseries\large|{\parbox[b][3.0cm][t]{7em}{\centering{\large\color{red}
   ```

   \dpt}\ \uI}}},text align={center}, raise=-3.5cm}, decorate] (\Aorig-\xi*\Asector:10cm) arc (\Aorig-\xi*\Asector:\Aorig-\xi*\Asector-\Asector:10);
   }
   % inner circle
   \draw[draw=white,fill = gray!10,thick] circle[radius = 4.6cm];
   \draw[draw=white,fill = gray!40,thick] circle[radius = 3.8cm];
   \draw[draw=white,fill = gray!10,thick] circle[radius = 3.5cm];

   ```
        \pgfmathsetmacro\uAAAangle{90}
        \coordinate (uAAA) at (\uAAAangle:3.7cm);
        \draw[decoration={text along path, text={|\bfseries\large|Internal Audit},text align={center}, raise=0.2cm}, decorate] (uAAA) arc (\uAAAangle:\uAAAangle-180:3.7);
        %%Label2
        \draw[decoration={text along path, text={|\bfseries\large|Economic Intelligence Unit},text align={center}, raise=0.2cm}, decorate] (\uAAAangle-180:3.7cm) arc (\uAAAangle-180:\uAAAangle-360:3.7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

   \end{document}

**What I want**

I want the text in each sector of the circle to follow along each sector's path like [image: this] in [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311028/aligning-text-along-a-sector-of-a-circle?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [image: that] in [that solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593603/need-help-with-a-pie-chart-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1) and not straight like the output of my code.

Comment: I want the texts to fold along the paths of each sector.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a lot more involved. The `\parbox[b][3.0cm][t]{7em}{...}` is the issue. You are trying to have the text span along a path. Since the text is long, you decided to place it into a bounded region `\parbox`, hence, you lost the path. The other solutions requires that you break the text line-by-line manually, which is your best option.